# Angular 2 form button Button handling

Tags: angular, button

Hi Folks hope someone can advise.

I have a form where admin users can create users which has validation on it.

They have now asked for the ability to edit / delete users. I have added the form components and can get the selected users details to display but I cannot get the system to do validation on the update button.

How do I call the onsubmit function on both buttons but distinguish between which button has been pressed?

otherwise how do I handle the 3 buttons so they all work accourdingly

Thanks
Andy

Comment: Please post your code !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach would be to have a variable store the type of submit action that was done and switch on that action inside of the `onSubmit` function.

**Add the variable and switch statement inside of your component**

```
export class AppComponent {

    private submitType: String;

    onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
      switch(this.submitType){
        case 'CREATE':
          // Do something
          break;
        case 'UPDATE':
          // Do someting else
          break;
        case 'DELETE':
          // Do another thing
          break;
      }
   }

}
```

**Then you can add multiple buttons to your form and update that variable when clicked**

```
  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
    <button name="create" type="submit" (click)="this.submitType = 'CREATE'">Create</button>
    <button name="update" type="submit" (click)="this.submitType = 'UPDATE'">Update</button>
    <button name="delete" type="submit" (click)="this.submitType = 'DELETE'">Delete</button>
  </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and answer, really appreciated.